# apache rewrite all hash tag to slash tag under one directory

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

How to rewrite all hash tag to slash tag under one directory? (apache)

http://www.domain.com/company/index#about => http://www.domain.com/company/index/about
http://www.domain.com/company/article#123456 => http://www.domain.com/company/article/123456
http://www.domain.com/company/events#October => http://www.domain.com/company/events/October

So, all the pages witch in `/company/`, rewrite `#` => `/`.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  //
}
```

Comment: Seems like you'd need to transform the HTML, since once you send out a hyperlink with a hash mark in it, the client doesn't send it back to the server. Have you tried mod_proxy_html?  You'll of course need to be prepared to do something with these URLs when you receive them with slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general all the browsers exclude the fragment part (#) from the request to the server. If you really want do it, you must rewrite the urls before call the server

```
function addHashtag2Pathname(url){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    if (a.pathname.substr(-1) != "/")
        a.pathname = a.pathname + '/';
    a.pathname += a.hash.replace(/^#/,'');
    a.hash = '';
    return a.href.replace(/#$/,'');
}
```

You can see this function in action here 
http://jsfiddle.net/bknE4/43/

Actually I haven't tried this below, but it should work...

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
   var newurl = addHashtag2Pathname(location.href);
   location.href = newurl;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate your web browser to `http://www.domain.com/company/events#October`, it will fetch the URL `http://www.domain.com/company/events` from the server. The server does not see the rest of the URL and can do nothing with it. Only Javascript can act on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  var a_tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < a_tags.length; i = i + 1) {
    var elem = a_tags[i];
    if (/company.*#/.test(elem.href)){
      elem.href = elem.href.replace('#', '/');
    }
  }
}
```

You might want to change the regexp in the if conditional to be more specific.
The same for the replace function.

However I would change the HTML server side instead if it is supposed to be permanent.